# What is this nut clamp called and how do you remove it?

Tags: bolts, hand-tools

I would like to remove the wheel that is being held in by this contraption:

[image]

I tried to use a standard socket wrench, but couldn't get just the right size: 1/2" or 13mm seems too small; 5/8" or 14mm seems too big.
Also, I'm not sure if there's a trick involving the black part.  What's that called? Is there a special technique? 
The other end of the rod looks the same.

Answer (score 5):

The hex is irrelevant, don't turn it.   The black part is the heart of the matter.  This is an [E-clip](https://www.google.com/search?q=e-clip&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en&client=safari&dlnr=1&sei=nR6dV8SAJoeUjwTGh4uQCQ).

Pop it off with a small screwdriver but control it with your finger - it WILL go flying!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The e-clips come off, but it doesn't seem any closer to removing the white part.  Is there another step after that?

Comment: There may be a set-screw, the part may be stuck there out of habit, or (less likely) it may be pressed on.

Comment: aka: *retaining ring*, for which they make spreader pliers. But e-clips you can do with a needle nose.